# passing Variable from PHP to Python

Tags: php, python

i have problem , i want to passing variable from php to python . 
why if my word contains space , in python cannt receive this words .
Example Code :

```
<?php 
$variable = "Test Variable Contains Space";

echo shell_exec("C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\hasil.py $variable ");

?>
```

in my python code :

```
import sys

variable = str(sys.argv[1])

print variable
```

the result i have from this code jut this words "Test" .

Comment: [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) is usually the best option. Albeit cmd might mess with it, Python usually employs a standard shell argument tokenizer.

Answer (score 1):

Bash commands interpret arguments as separated by spaces, therefore, `Test Variable Contains Space` seems like 4 different arguments. To fix this, you need to surround it with double quotes:

```
... \"$variable\" ");
```

Full code:

```
<?php 
$variable = "Test Variable Contains Space";

echo shell_exec("C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\hasil.py \"$variable\" ");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add "." after url part is completed.

```
echo shell_exec("C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\hasil.py". $variable);
```